# jQuery selector id not recognized issue

Tags: jquery, class, selector

```
    <div class="ground">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box" id="block1">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="box" id="block2">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="box" id="block3">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="box" id="block4">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#block1').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    });
});
```

This is my script.
Here, I am trying to make division with id do certain thing when clicked.
However, this simple code just won't work.

When I put div with "block1" as an id outside the div with class=ground, it works ok.
But whenever I put in inside other tags, selector just does not recognize the id and nothing happens when I click it.

To my knowledge id should be recognized regardless of where it belongs, isn't it?

Comment: It will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/5uZJ9/

Comment: Can changing css properties affect this? This is really weird.
Edit: Indeed, removing css properties of "ground" and "row" makes it work.. what could be causing this?

Comment: Ok.. I think I got the culprit.. it was display:relative; that was causing it.